# Find the minimum and display the variable name in python

Tags: python

You have got three variables like

```
   a = 1
   b = 2
   c = 3
```

and you find the minimum can you somehow display the variable name instead of the value it has

Example

```
   d = min[a,b,c]
```

after this operation d should become c since c is the greatest. Or maybe there's some alternative way because i want to assign the variable name in another operation afterwards.

Comment: "d should become c" -- ignoring the fact that it should become `a`, since `a` is the smallest... what do you mean by that?  do you want it to be the string `'c'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put variables into a dictionary and call `min()` with specifying dictionary `get` as a `key`:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> data = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}
>>> min(data, key=data.get)
'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do that. Instead, you should do something like:

```
data = {
  'a' : 1
  'b' : 2
  'c' : 3
}

# get the minimum item, by the value.
smallest = min(data.items(), key = lambda item: item[1])

data[smallest] = my_new_value
```

Comment: Or `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` if you want to avoid lambdas.